# Deterministic process, what is it ? how can i get a better intuition for it?

Tags: autocorrelation, time-series, autoregressive-model

so I was following this code where the author cleans the data for a time series problem. He does some feature engineering , all is well and good
until he does this

```
    y = train.unstack(['store_nbr', 'family']).loc[sdate:edate]
    fourier = CalendarFourier(freq = 'W', order = 4)
    dp = DeterministicProcess(index = y.index,
                              order = 1,
                              seasonal = False,
                              constant = False,
                              additional_terms = [fourier],
                              drop = True)
```

could someone explain what a deterministic process is and how can I know more about it?
This is the [link](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.deterministic.DeterministicProcess.html) to the documentation of the deterministic process mentioned above.
The problem I am trying to understand is a time series analysis to predict sales 16 days into the future.

Comment: Can you provide more details and context about this snippet of code?  The function DeterministicProcess() is not a standard function (at least not in any language that I am aware of).  Could you update your question to provide its definition or a link to its documentation?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome I have edited the question, please let me know what you think?

Comment: Deterministic really just means "not random". Following the documentation, that seems to be exactly what this is: a non-random process. Something that generates values which are *not* random.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what would be the purpose of those values what can they tell us about the data?

Comment: @TaqiHussain that's impossible for us to know. All you tell us here is that they're deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

A random process is a collection of random variables $\{X_t\colon t \in \mathbb T\}$, one variable for each time instant $t$ in the *index set* $\mathbb T$. Typically, $\mathbb T$ is the real line $\mathbb R$, or the integers $\mathbb Z$ or infinite subsets thereof, but $\mathbb T$ could be a finite set too (in which case, people often prefer simpler terminology such as a vector random variable or a vector of random variables).

A random process is called deterministic if all the random variables comprising the process are (known) *functions* of a *finite* set of or random variables.  For example, $\{X_t\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ where for each $t$, $X_t = \cos(2\pi f_0 t + \Theta)$ or $X_t = A \cos(2\pi f_0 t + \Theta)$ where $\Theta$ and $A$ are random variables , are examples of deterministic random processes. If $\Theta\sim U(0,2\pi)$, then both processes are *wide-sense-stationary* processes too.

The reason for the somewhat pejorative adjective *deterministic* is that from a few observations of each sample path, it is possible to *determine* (or predict for the more progressive folks) the entire sample path.